# Membership Custom Provider Fails Invocation in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-membershipprovider

hi guys here is my app config

```
   <membership
 defaultProvider="TheTWMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="TheTWMembershipProvider"
            type="Model.TWMembershipProvider, Model"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

**this is the error i get when I try to login**

```
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Source Error: 





Line 99:         <clear/>
Line 100:        <add name="TheTWMembershipProvider"
Line 101:            type="Model.TWMembershipProvider, Model"/>
Line 102:      </providers>
Line 103:    </membership>
```

I got Dll Named `Model.Dll` With Custom Provider
Named 
class `TWMembershipProvider : System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider`

I impliment

```
 public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

please help!

Comment: The error message suggests there was an error calling the constructor of your membership provider. You should have an inner exception which will contain more details.

Comment: No constructor... And if i had one.  How to find inner exception?

Comment: GOT IT! had static item that threw exception.
@RichardDeeming post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message suggests there was an error calling the constructor (instance or static) of your membership provider. Remember that field initializers count as part of the constructor!

You should have an inner exception which will contain more details.

Comment: So how do I go about seeing this inner exception?

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov: If it's not visible in the Yellow Screen of Death, or in your own application-level error handler, it should be in the application event log.